# Twitter dataset to train word embeddings

Tags: data-request, nlp

I'm working on a project related to manipulating word embeddings. In order to do this, I need to train them myself on twitter data. Given Twitter's policy, I am unable to find a suitable dataset. Does anyone have one or know where I can find one?

The dataset should:

- contain public tweets
- have no specific topic, just need lots of tweets
- be pre-processed

Answer (score 1):

[Tweet Sentiment Extraction](https://www.kaggle.com/c/tweet-sentiment-extraction/data?select=train.csv)

Kaggle supports a variety of dataset publication formats.

[Kaggle Twitter Datasets](https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=twitter%20data%20in%3Adatasets)

You need to have an account to download the datasets. You can find the code for preprocessing in the kernels tab.